# Update JSON with user input and convert to XML

Tags: jquery, json

I am taking CSV data, displaying it to the user with input fields.   I am looking to take these values update the Json and converted to XML.  Is it possible to update Json with user inputs or is there a different way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(
        'CSV.php', 
        function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                newDiv = $('<div/>').addClass('row').appendTo('#showdata');
                $('<div class="options">Payment Format: <select name="Payment_Format"><option value="CCC" selected="selected">Company to Company</option><option value="PPP">Company to Person</option></select> </div>').appendTo(newDiv);
                $('<div class="field">' + value + '</div>').appendTo(newDiv);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it in a form? You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert the data to json :)

Comment: Its currently not in a form, the final result needs to be in XML format.  I'm just confused about how to take user inputs to update the data that is currently in Json format and then reformat it or XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will pretty much need to follow this flow:

1. Parse the JSON into an "object" native to your programming language (this should be easy since you are using javascript)
2. Retrieve user input and update the object accordingly (`obj.name = user_input`)
3. Convert the object to XML (ew) and output it. Check out [an example of this](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/) from a [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442242/whats-the-best-way-to-serialize-javascript-objects-to-xml)

I'm not going to force you to use JSON entirely but I will ask you to consider it if you can. It plays much nicer with JS and there are tons of libraries out there for other languages. Not to mention it uses significantly less data than XML. If your hands are tied on this though, this is the approach to take

Comment: My client needs an XML exported.  Question - in step 2, what is the best way to add all the keys and values of the JSON and add them to the new object while going through the $.each loop?

Comment: What are you looping through? when you parse the JSON (step 1) the object is created for you and will already have all of the keys/values from the input in the object. Step 2 is just updating the ones you want to change. Make sense?

Comment: Well since there are 2 things happening simultaneously: 1. Data is being displayed to the user via HTML with options to change values and 2. The Object containing the data that was imported and the user-edited values is converted to XML.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the process...  But, My XML is quite complex and has a lot of nesting.  I am having a hard time figuring out how to organize the object for my XML requirements.

Comment: That is totally going to depend on how your XML is structured. @Jordan eluded to this in another answer, there are countless ways to organize it. I'm not sure where your problem is right now but if it has to do with serializing your JS object to JSON the articles that have been posted in the answers here are great places to start on that

Comment: I finally got up to the point of doing step 2 of the process that you described.  But, I cannot get the object attribute to update based on user input.  I am doing a console.log and not seeing the update.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

To update JSON you have to decode it into a JavaScript object (which `$.getJSON` does for you. Then you manipulate the JavaScript object just like you would any other.

To get XML from your JavaScript you first need to decide what kind of serialization you want to use, because JSON does not map naturally to XML. For example, say you have this JavaScript object:

```
{ person : { name : "Paul", parents : [ "Alice", "Bob" ] } }
```

What's the correct XML representation of this? Is it this:

```
<person name="Paul">
  <parent>Alice</parent>
  <parent>Bob</parent>
</person>
```

Or this?

```
<person>
  <name>Paul</name>
  <parents>
    <person name="Alice" />
    <person name="Bob" />
  </parents>
</person>
```

There are practically endless variations on this and no consensus on what's best.

Once you've figured out what serialization you need then you have to generate the XML. It's [not hard to do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_create_a_DOM_tree) but if you're looking for something you can just drop into your project you'll probably have to do some searching to find something that meets your needs (since you haven't specified them). To get you started [here's a previous discussion on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442242/whats-the-best-way-to-serialize-javascript-objects-to-xml).

Comment: Thank you for such a great explanation! I am still a bit stuck on the first part: since $.getJson creates the object, can you provide some sample code show how I would add the JSON data to the object and include the user input? My code above is only printing it out to display to the user.

Comment: That would depend on what your markup looks like and what your JSON looks like, really. But [here's a good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on working with JavaScript objects.